# Nested sequence of sets in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

How can I prove that nested sequence of non-empty bounded closed convex sets in Hilbert space have nonempty intersection?

I just don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the weak topology for Hilbert space?

Comment: I don't know what it is.

Comment: What do you know about closed bounded convex sets in a Hilbert space, then?

Comment: Proof without weak topology is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/900981/).

Answer (score 3):

This is Cantors Intersection Theorem. The (simple) proof can be found [here](https://planetmath.org/CantorsIntersectionTheorem) for example. You need to use the fact that closed bounded convex subsets in a Hilbert space H are [weakly compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology).

Comment: Unfortunately, if he doesn't know what is the weak topology, he probably also doesn't know anything about "weakly compact".  This illustrates the standard wisdom: For problems with homework, seek help from the instructor.