# Intersection of a descending sequence of closed convex bounded subsets in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested sequence of sets in Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79628/nested-sequence-of-sets-in-hilbert-space)

$\{A_n\}$ is a descending sequence of closed convex bounded subsets in Hilbert space. Why can't the intersection be empty?
I'm not sure how to start proving that, I will be glad to get a hint. I think the following theorem might help: 
In Hilbert space every non empty, closed, convex subset contains a unique element of smallest norm.

Comment: I don't think there's any possible about it.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: In case you didn't know, the "possible" (and everything else in t.b.'s comment) is part of the automatically generated message that the software posts when someone votes to close as a duplicate of another question.  It appeared because t.b. was first to vote to close (and I guess they include "possible" because it should also apply to less clear-cut cases).

Comment: @Jonas, I did not know that. Thanks.