# Prove that $\bigcap_n K_n \neq ∅$.

Tags: hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Discuss the validity of the following
>   statement: If ${K_n}$ is a decreasing sequence of nonempty, bounded, closed
>   convex sets in $H$, then $\bigcap_n K_n \neq ∅$.

My work:

Let $L_n=\inf\{\|x\|:x\in K_n\}$. Then there is a unique $x_n\in K_n$ such that $\|x_n\|=L_n$. Now I wanted to prove that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is cauchy but stuck. I found a similar solution here

[Intersection of nested closed bounded convex sets in Euclidean space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900981/intersection-of-nested-closed-bounded-convex-sets-in-euclidean-space)

but was not helpful because as I think it has some mistakes. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: What mistakes?  This looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Ok then in order to show that $(x_n+x_m)/2 \in E_m$ by convexity we need to have $x_n\in E_m$. But $m>n$. So how do we know that $x_n\in E_m$?

Comment: And what is $R$ in that solution?

Comment: I guess $E_n$ was intended, and $R=R_*$, but I haven't checked closely the details.

Comment: That is why I mentioned that it has mistakes. And the last statement does not seems to be a contradiction as $R$ is the limit of an increasing sequence.

Comment: For now I've deleted my answer.  It said this: (BEGIN QUOTE) Let $\ell^2$ be the Hilbert space of sequences $(c_1,c_2,c_3,\ldots)$ of complex numbers such that $\sum_k |c_k|^2<\infty$. Let
$$
K_n = \Big\{ (\,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n-1}, c_n, c_{n+1},c_{n+2},,\ldots) : \forall k\ge n,\ c_k\ge 0\text{ and } \sum_{k=n+1} c_k=1 \Big\}.
$$
Then $\ell^2\supseteq K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq\cdots$ and these are closed, convex, and bounded, and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n = \varnothing$. (END QUOTE) However, now I'm not sure these sets are closed. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: They are closed if the function that takes a sequence of non-negative numbers to its sum is continuous on the set of sequences of non-negative numbers whose sum is finite.  That's unproblematic if one looks only at sequences of length $N$ for some integer $N$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $(\,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n-1}, \,\underbrace{1/n, \ldots,1/n}_n\,,0,0,0,\ldots)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, because the norm of that vector is $1/n$.  Hence the subsets I described are not actually closed. ${}\qquad{}$